# table is misaligned and scrolling is not working initially after refreshing it behaves like normal table with proper alignment

Tags: javascript

**I applied this javascript to table in cshtml page**

```
 var table = $('#usertableStart').DataTable({
            "order": [[0, "desc"]],
            "scrollX": true,
            "bAutoWidth": true,
            "initComplete": function () {
                $('.loader').hide();
           },
            "drawCallback": function () {
                $('.loader').hide();
            }
        });
```

After applying this javascript, Scrolling and alignment are working fine after refreshing the screen, Not in the initial phase. what code should i do for this problem?

**Below attached screenshots:**

**1. At the initial stage:**

[image: at initial stage]

**2. After refreshing the tab:**

[image: after refreshing the tab]

css is applied on datatable is like

```
.dataTables_wrapper {
width: 100%
}

.dataTables_wrapper > .row:first-child {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px 20px
}

    .dataTables_wrapper > .row:first-child input.form-control, .dataTables_wrapper > .row:first-child select.form-control {
        height: 32px;
        padding: 6px 12px;
    }

.dataTables_wrapper .tableStyle {
    margin-top: 0 !Important
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scrollBody .tableStyle thead tr th {
    padding: 0px 12px !Important
}

.dataTables_wrapper table.dataTable thead th, .dataTables_wrapper table.dataTable tfoot th {
    font-weight: normal
}

.dataTables_wrapper.no-footer .dataTables_scrollBody {
    border-bottom: 0 !important
}

.dataTables_wrapper > .row:last-child {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 15px 20px;
}
```

Comment: As your question is looking incomplete. I think you can write this piece of code in `document.ready` block.

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot and JavaScript

Comment: @ASHISHSHARMA please prefer attached screenshot  for your  reference

Comment: is that column alignment is the problem?

Comment: Have you checked what *`bAutoWidth`* this does?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale if i do not apply bAutowidth but didn't get any fruitful result.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale there is one more issue is that table header is not scroll at initial stage.

Comment: Can you provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so anyone can try to check and diagnose what is the problem, is it in CSS or anything else!

Comment: Hi, Lib version? And what's your HTML ?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale do you mean live link ?

Comment: can write this piece of code in document.ready

Comment: @shreya Yes, or where I/we can produce the same behavior!

Comment: @ASHISHSHARMA  I already wrote in document.ready

Comment: http://implement-onboarding.azurewebsites.net/Login
UserName : adminUser
Password : adminUser

Comment: @PrashantPimpale  i attached link in the above comment.

Comment: Try:`.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll {
    /* clear: both; */   Remove this
}`

Comment: @shreya Remove *clear:both* from `dataTables_scroll` class

Comment: And then check!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i am not able to solve with this.

Comment: Why is the CSS for `dataTables_scroll` class? can you post it